Existing app no longer runs in emulator or from app store, Firestore initialization failure
*** update below***
I have an existing app on both app stores.  It's built using Ionic / Angular / Firebase Firestore.  The existing app store version runs fine, but I have to update it to target the latest Android version by Aug 31.  The app runs fine on my local machine using "ionic serve" but the app will NOT run using the emulators (both xCode and Android Studio) and will not run from a Google app bundle uploaded to the Play Store (internal testing release).  The app crashes immediately.
The errors in logcat from Android Studio report a failure to initialize the database:

W: Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found. This usually means that com.google.gms:google-services was not applied to your gradle project.


E: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process xxx-process-name-xxx. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

I haven't changed the code from the running version, and it runs fine from an "ionic serve" command which initializes the database successfully.  I have the following in my app.module.ts source.


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence(),

Any ideas where to start debugging this?

the app runs correctly using "ionic serve" and a browser (chrome) using localhost:8100

the app crashed immediately when run from Android Studio (Koala 2024.1.1 Patch 1)
and xCode (version 15.4)

the app crashed immediately after building the app (android studio) and uploading it to the Google Play store in Closed Testing.


=== UPDATE ===
I believe I have updated all the modules (Ionic, Capacitor, Angular, Firebase/Firestore).  The app no longer runs correctly with a local 'ionic serve' and Chrome browser.  The result is simply a blank screen on the browser.  The only messages I see in the console are my app tracking console.log messages that show I am executing through the code in main.ts.
Here is the output from 'ionic info'
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 7.2.0 (C:\Users\Rick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 8.2.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 18.2.0
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 18.2.0
   @angular/cli                  : 18.2.0
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 11.0.1

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 6.1.1
   @capacitor/android : 6.1.1
   @capacitor/core    : 6.1.1
   @capacitor/ios     : 6.1.1

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.4
   native-run  : 2.0.1

System:

   NodeJS : v20.11.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 10.5.2
   OS     : Windows 10

@stackoverblows mentioned that I need to update the awesome-cordova-packages, but I was under the impression that the new capacitor plugins replace the awesome packages.  For example, I have installed @capacitor/geolocation@6.0.1 instead of the awesome-cordova-plugins/device-orientation.  I've tried to read through the Capacitor update/upgrade pages and that's what I interpreted.
Please let me know what additional info you need.  I'm plain stuck.  My next step is to start over with a brand-new app and slowly add my code in until it breaks.  That seems to me such a brute-force method.
thanks,

"I haven't changed the code from the running version," - heres your issue. Make sure to follow the update guide from ionic team:  https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/6-0#android.

Thanks for that link, Stackoverblows, but I have tried for 2 days to go through that upgrade process, both using the migration tools and the manual steps using the CLI.  The upgrade is still not successful, because it looks like I need to update a lot of vomponents, including Capacitor, Firestore, Firebase App-check.  Unfortunately I don't have the time and resources and testing capacility to update so many components of the app and re-factor the app itself for the new versions.

My app is currently targeting Android API version 33 and Google has given a deadline of Aug 31 to target 34 or higher.  I just want to run the same code with a target of API 34 to satisfy Google.  The app runs fine on my Pixel 8 running Android 14, so I know it will work on that API.

You're going to spend a lot more time trying to figure all this out rather than taking the actual time and updating/refactoring your app. Unfortunately this cannot be bypassed.

thanks.  I estimate it will take 6-8 weeks to refactor and go through all the testing.  Plus, I've ost my primary coder so I have to go "learn and understand" everything he did.  That's not the system's fault.  I will have to request the extension from Google.

@StackoverBlows  I now have all the modules updated to current versions and followed the migration steps.  None of the auto migration steps worked, so i did all the inst by hand.  I believe I have the env now updated.  I have followed what I could figure out about refactoring the code itself.  But, I now have an app that does nothing.  I run the app and get just a blank screen, both with 'ionic serve' with browser and in Android Studio.  I have console.logs in main.ts that show up, but the next code mod should be app.component.ts and it never gets there.  I'm stuck.  Any ideas where to start?

check in the android studio logcat, it should say something. what does it say?

there is >100 lines in logcat, mostly I and D messages, a few Warns and a few Error messages.  None of the error messages mean anything to me:

E  Seed missing signature.  E  Failed to write a new fake index.
2024-08-12 16:58:05.071  6664-6725  chromium                com.gemedot.parel                    E  Simple Cache Backend: cache directory inaccessible right after creation; path:              E  [ERROR:disk_cache.cc(208)] Unable to create cache

after these 4 errors, more D and I messages, "registering plugin...." and then "App Started" and about 30 messages "Handling local request....."

the last few messages:  "Ionic Native: deviceready event fired",  "Handling local request",  "app_time_stats...."     Compiler allocated 5174KB to compile...."   "Installing profile for com.gemedot.parel"   "background concurrent mark compact GC freed...."    "ApkAssets: deleting an ApkAssets object '' and /data/app........"

I can post the full logcat output somewhere if that helps.  It means nothing to me, unfortunately.  I'm not sure how to get a better format of the few EROR logcat lines.

Ok so this is why we all need to learn how to ask a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. because you missed a lot of info about your project.

with that being said, the android logcat can be confusing with all the bs it says but it does point you in the right direction. So you stated "Ionic Native: deviceready event fired". This leads me to believe you are sill using old ionic native plugins and have not migrated to the new awesome-cordova-packages (which is needed).

So... go to your console and type in ionic info and post that info here. Also edit your question with new details please. https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/info
